# after validating looped if statement else statement is not working

Tags: c#, .net-core, model-view-controller

I have a if elseif else statement like as follows

```cs
if (check1)   ---- 1
{
    if(check2)   ----2
    {
    }
}
else if (checkother1) ---- 3
{
    if(checkother2) -----4
}
else  ------- 5
{
    do this
}
return someview
```

when the code hits first if statement and if the condition validates it will go inside check2 if statement after doing the validation it is entering the last else statement(5) correctly .

But when the code enters the 3rd if statement and after validating the 4th if statement if is not validated it is showing error properly but if it get validated it is directly going to the return

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("CanditateId,CanditateFirstName,CanditateLastName,CanditateAadhar,CanditatePancard,CanditateEmail,CanditateGender,CanditateLocation,CanditateMaritialStatus,CanditateDoj,CanditateActDoa,CanditateDesignation,CanditateDepartment,CanditateTeam,CanditateAddress,CanditateAltNumber,CanditateIdNumber,CanditateBaseLocation,CanditateManager,CanditatePrefix,CanditateMobile")] Canditateinfo canditateinfo)
        {
            var canditateinfos = await _context.Canditateinfos.FindAsync(id);
            if (id != canditateinfo.CanditateId)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try 
                {
                    var isAAdharAlreadyExists = _context.Canditateinfos.Any(x => x.CanditateAadhar == canditateinfo.CanditateAadhar);
                    var isPanCardAlreadyExists = _context.Canditateinfos.Any(x => x.CanditatePancard == canditateinfo.CanditatePancard);
                    if (canditateinfos.CanditateAadhar != canditateinfo.CanditateAadhar)
                    {
                        if (isAAdharAlreadyExists)
                        {
                            ModelState.AddModelError("CanditateAadhar", "User with this aadhar already exists");
                            return View(canditateinfo);
                        }

                    }
                    else if (canditateinfos.CanditatePancard != canditateinfo.CanditatePancard)
                    {
                        if (isPanCardAlreadyExists)
                        {
                            ModelState.AddModelError("CanditatePancard", "User with this Pan Number already exists");
                            return View(canditateinfo);
                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        canditateinfo.EnteredBy = canditateinfos.EnteredBy;
                        canditateinfo.EnteredDate = canditateinfos.EnteredDate;
                        canditateinfo.DeleteFlag = canditateinfos.DeleteFlag;
                        canditateinfo.IsActive = canditateinfos.IsActive;
                        canditateinfo.CanditateId = canditateinfos.CanditateId;
                        canditateinfo.UpdatedBy = HttpContext.Session.GetString("username");
                        canditateinfo.UpdatedDate = DateTime.Now;
                        _context.Update(canditateinfo);
                        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                        TempData["SuccessMessage"] = "Canditate Updated Successfully";
                        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
                    }
                }
                catch 
                {
                }
                
            }
            return View(canditateinfo);
        }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems

Comment: also obviously ... your else would not be called if 1st true and 2nd false  or 3th true and 4th false ... so it basically means that if you change pancard or aadhar and they are not already  in database would be never updated but also there will be no error

Comment: 5 is never executed if either 1 or 3 succeeds. The inner checks 2 and 4 do not matter for 5 to be executed or not.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes The code deviates from the simplyfied pseudo code in that it has `return` statements in the nested `if`s. I layed that out in my answer for OP.

Comment: Unrelated: What if `!ModelState.IsValid`? You might want to spare yourself one level of nesting and handle this with a `if(!ModelState.IsValid) return ...;` and then go on to code the rest of the method assuming the ModelState _is_ valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested `if`s do not matter for the outer control flow. (Yours **do**, though but hear me out ;D )

In ...

```
if ( condition1 )
{
   // body1
}
else if( condition2 )
{
   // body2
}
else
{
   // body3
}
// aftermath
```

... "body3" will be executed if **and only if** *neither* `condition1` *nor* `condition2` evaluate to `true`.

That is regardless of any further nested `if` statements in "body1" or "body2". (**Given, there are no fancy `goto`s or `return`s or the like...** - more on this further down)

That also means:

- If `condition1` is true, the flow is "body1", "aftermath" (Note that in this case, it doesn't even matter what `condition2` evals to.)
- If `condition1` is false and `condition2` is true, the flow is "body2", "aftermath"
- If `condition1` is false and `condition2` is false, the flow is "body3", "aftermath"

---

Now, **in your code, you do have `return`s inside the inner `if` statements**. This of course **does** influence the control flow.

They will "bail out" early. **That means ...**

```
if (condition1)
{
    if (condition1_1)
    {
        return retVal1; // If 1 && 1_1 => Rest of method is not executed
    }
//  if !condition1_1 we end up at "aftermath" for the the next instruction 
//  because condition1 was true!!
} 
else if (condition2)
{
    if (condition2_1)
    {
        return retVal2; // If 2 && 2_2 => Rest of the method is not executed
    }
//  if !condition2_1 we end up at "aftermath" for the the next instruction 
//  because condition2 was true!!
} 
else
{
    // body3
}

// aftermath
```

So, if you want "body3" to be executed in those cases where the nested `if`s *do **not** bail out*, you need to restructure this logic.

As far as I can see, those are sanity tests. I think if you do something like this, it should work as expected:

```
if (condition1 && condition1_1)
{ // here, BOTH primary AND secondary condition MUST evaluate to true
  // so that this branch is entered
    return retVal1; // If 1 && 1_1 => Rest of method is not executed
} 
else if (condition2 && condition2_1)
{
    return retVal2; // If 2 && 2_2 => Rest of the method is not executed
} 
else
{
    // body3
}
```

which can be simplyfied to

```
if (condition1 && condition1_1)
{
    return retVal1; // If 1 && 1_1 => Rest of method is not executed
} 

if (condition2 && condition2_1)
{
    return retVal2; // If 2 && 2_2 => Rest of the method is not executed
} 

// what was before body3
```

Note that in `if (condition1 && condition1_1)` C#/.NET is so kind to evaluate `condition1_1` only if `condition1` evaluates to `true`. Otherwise the whole expression evaluates to false. Which is correct:
If `condition1` is false already, then `condition1 && condition1_1` can never be `true` regardless of what `condition1_1` would evaluate to, so it can stop early.

So, it is safe to write something like `if( x is not null && x.IsValid )`.

---

Fun fact:

Your original code would probably work as expected **without the `else`s**:

```
if( condition1 )
{
  if ( subcondition1 )
  {
// condition && subcondition == true
     return errorCase1;
  }
}

// you can land here if one of condition1 or subcondition1 is false
// and therefore go on to execute :
if( condition2 )
{
  if ( subcondition2 )
  {
     return errorCase2;
  }
}

// happy path here, aka "body3"
```